# The t, p, k sounds in stop, spit, skip when we whisper

Tags: pronunciation

Technically speaking, when we whisper, do the t, p, k sounds in stop, spit, skip become the same as d, b, g?

Comment: Pretty much. Different people's actual pronunciation will vary, of course, but once the aspiration and voicing are eliminated, there is very little left to distinguish these phonemes, at least at normal speech rates.

Comment: Not for me. /t p k/ aren't aspirated after /s/ even when speaking. But there's subtle difference between /p t k/ and /b d g/ when whispered.

Comment: That's a hard comparison to make because /sb/, /sd/,and /sg/ do not exist in the English phonemic repertoire even when voiced. So you're asking native speakers to both sound out something that is already hard (or impossible), and then to add another, rare change on it (whispering).

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/620545/2085).

Answer (score 2):

Even when *not* whispering, /p, t, k/ generally become /b, d, g/ after an /s/, as [Geoff Lindsey explains here.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=U37hX8NPgjQ)